# Entity Framework 5 not updating row with xml string

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to save a string (68kb in size) containing utf-8 encoded xml into SQL Server 2012 using Entity Framework 5. I'm using the code-first approach.

However, for some of my xml strings (but not all) it saves an empty string and none of the xml at all. Using breakpoints confirms that the data is being assigned prior to `SaveChanges()` being called.

Here's the method I'm using to update a particular row in the database:

```
    public void LogResponseMessage(MessageBase msg, DebugLog debugLog)
    {
        // Serialize the message using a helper class
        string XMLMsg = SerializationHelper.XMLSerializeObject(msg, m_SerializationTypes, true);

        debugLog.DtTmResponseLogged = DateTime.Now;
        debugLog.ResponseMsg = XMLMsg;

        using (var db = new LoggerContext())
        {
            db.DebugLogs.Attach(debugLog);
            var Entry = db.Entry(debugLog);
            // Flag the updated columns as having been modified
            Entry.Property(x => x.DtTmResponseLogged).IsModified = true;
            Entry.Property(x => x.ResponseMsg).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

`debugLog.ResponseMsg` is the column I'm having trouble with. `DebugLog` is a class which contains the column definitions. `ResponseMsg` gets assigned an XML serialized .NET object which I'm then wanting to save. I'm flagging the column as modified but for some particular strings it just saves an empty string. No exceptions are thrown by EF, and I can view the XML sitting in `debugLog.ResponseMsg` using the debugger. The string property `ResponseMsg` has the `[MaxLength]` attribute set and the column gets created in SQL Server as an `nvarchar(max)`.

My initial thoughts are it's some kind of encoding or size issue, but I'm not making much headway with either - can anyone shed any light on this?

**Update**: It seems to be a string length issue. Strings > 43678 characters do not get written, strings <= 43678 do get written. I'm still at a loss as to where this limit is coming from.

**Update2**: Have created a project from scratch which updates a single table and am seeing exactly the same issue, so I know it's not a "mangled migration" issue either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here is the, quite frankly, incredulous solution in case anyone else runs into the same "problem".

The data was there all along. But if, in Visual Studio 2012, you use SQL Server Object Explorer and choose "view data", for nvarchar columns with more than 43678 characters in length you don't see the data (ResponseMsg column looks empty):

[image: No Data]

But if you write you own T-SQL query, then you see the data in the results pane:

[image: Data]

Argh. And this is why I should be using SQL Management Studio!